# Laravel horizon not processing jobs

Tags: laravel, laravel-queue, laravel-horizon, laravel-jobs

I install laravel horizon on a laravel 5.7 project and config it like this:

```
    'domain' => null,
    'path' => 'horizon',
    'use' => 'default',
    'prefix' => env('HORIZON_PREFIX', 'horizon:'),
    'waits' => [
        'redis:default' => 60,
    ],
    'trim' => [
        'recent' => 60,
        'completed' => 60,
        'recent_failed' => 10080,
        'failed' => 10080,
        'monitored' => 10080,
    ],
   'fast_termination' => false,
   'memory_limit' => 64,
   'environments' => [
    'production'=>[
        'save_report' => [
                'connection' => 'redis',
                'queue' => ['save_report'],
                'balance' => 'auto',
                'processes' => 5,
                'tries' => 1,
            ],
    ],
        'local' => [
            'save_report' => [
                'connection' => 'redis',
                'queue' => ['save_report'],
                'balance' => 'auto',
                'processes' => 5,
                'tries' => 1,
            ],

        ],
    ],
```

This is full horizon config, and I'm almost sure it's ok.
But in the horizon panel, all the job is paused!

[image: paused jobs]

`php artisan horizon` is active on my terminal.

Comment: Please provide full horizon configuration

Comment: @AnuraghKP I add full horizon config.

Comment: Have you set your environment in ```.env``` file properly and also queue name that you have dispatched the job must be available in config

Comment: @AnuraghKP, after upgrading to another version of horizon, it's working! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 13):

Check that your environment in .env is "production"

The environment name must match Horizon configuration.